# JAVA Matrix-Vector-Multiplication 100 times slower than C-Version

Tags: java, android, c, performance, android-ndk

im working on performance-differences between Android JAVA- and Android NDK-applications.
I performed a Matrix4D-Vector4D Transformation on more than 90000 vertices as an example for 3D Graphics.

It seemes, that the JAVA Version is nearly **100 times slower** than the C-Version. Did i something wrong? Does anyone have similar experiences?

my Java-Code for transformation:

```
        long t1 = System.nanoTime();
        for ( int i = 0; i < vCount; i++)
        {

            Vector4 vOut = new Vector4();
            Vector4 v = vertices[i];

            vOut.v_[0] = v.v_[0] * matrix[0].v_[0];
            vOut.v_[1] = v.v_[0] * matrix[0].v_[1];
            vOut.v_[2] = v.v_[0] * matrix[0].v_[2];
            vOut.v_[3] = v.v_[0] * matrix[0].v_[3];

            vOut.v_[0] += v.v_[1] * matrix[1].v_[0];
            vOut.v_[1] += v.v_[1] * matrix[1].v_[1];
            vOut.v_[2] += v.v_[1] * matrix[1].v_[2];
            vOut.v_[3] += v.v_[1] * matrix[1].v_[3];

            vOut.v_[0] += v.v_[2] * matrix[2].v_[0];
            vOut.v_[1] += v.v_[2] * matrix[2].v_[1];
            vOut.v_[2] += v.v_[2] * matrix[2].v_[2];
            vOut.v_[3] += v.v_[2] * matrix[2].v_[3];

            vOut.v_[0] += v.v_[3] * matrix[3].v_[0];
            vOut.v_[1] += v.v_[3] * matrix[3].v_[1];
            vOut.v_[2] += v.v_[3] * matrix[3].v_[2];
            vOut.v_[3] += v.v_[3] * matrix[3].v_[3]; 

            vertices[i] = vOut;

        }
        long t2 = System.nanoTime();        
        long diff = t2 - t1;        
        double ms = (double)(diff / 1000000.0f);
        Log.w("GL2JNIView", String.format("ms %.2f ", ms));
```

Performance (Transform > 90 000 Vertices | Android 4.0.4 SGS II):
(Median-value of 200 runs)

```
JAVA-Version:   2 FPS
C-Version:    190 FPS
```

Comment: Have you tried using parallel arrays instead of objects?

Comment: no, for now i just want to examine single-thread/core performance.

Comment: that's alright, parallel arrays refers to putting every field of an object into its own array, instead of having a single array of objects, it's just a different way to layout your data. So in this case you'd have four arrays, one for every element of the vector4.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You create a new Vector4 in each Iteration. From my own experience using new inside loops can cause unexpected performance problems in Android.

Comment: thanks. With loop-outside temp-vector i got now 8.3 FPS, so that was an issue. so we have ony 25 times slower now!

Answer (score 0):

AFAIK, Android Java implementation is thru a virtual machine called [Dalvik](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dalvik_%28software%29) which has a different instruction set than the [JVM](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jvm) and does not use any [just-in-time compilation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Just-in-time_compilation) techniques to dynamically translate some bytecodes to machine code, but just interpret them. So Dalvik is obviously slower on CPU bound tasks rthan C.

This might change in very recent [Android](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Android_%28operating_system%29) systems.

Comment: is right, also Google Android staff is shouting everywhere "NDK is for performance critic operations.".

Comment: yeah, but i think Android > 4.0 has JIT: [link](http://www.webupd8.org/2012/07/android-x86-404-ics-rc2-released-with.html)

Comment: This is why I mentioned "very recent Android systems"

Answer (score 0):

You also should change your loop. In addition to the answer by @toopok4k3 you should try these things:

- Dump the for loop and just catch an ArrayIndexOutOfBounds exception. You have a large enough loop to make up for the overhead of the try/catch.
- If the matrix array and the values they contain aren't changing from one loop iteration to the next then assign them to constants outside of the loop. De-referencing arrays and accessing member variables aren't nearly as fast as local variables.
- Since v.v_[] is used several times, assign it to a local variable and use it 4 times before getting the next one.

I am assuming the values are doubles in the version below.

```
int i = 0;
try  
{
    Vector4 vOut = new Vector4();
    final double m0v0 = matrix[0].v_[0];
    final double m0v1 = matrix[0].v_[1];
    final double m0v2 = matrix[0].v_[2];
    final double m0v3 = matrix[0].v_[3];
    final double m1v0 = matrix[1].v_[0];
    final double m1v1 = matrix[1].v_[1];
    final double m1v2 = matrix[1].v_[2];
    final double m1v3 = matrix[1].v_[3];
    final double m2v0 = matrix[2].v_[0];
    final double m2v1 = matrix[2].v_[1];
    final double m2v2 = matrix[2].v_[2];
    final double m2v3 = matrix[2].v_[3];
    final double m3v0 = matrix[3].v_[0];
    final double m3v1 = matrix[3].v_[1];
    final double m3v2 = matrix[3].v_[2];
    final double m3v3 = matrix[3].v_[3];

    while (true)
    {
        Vector4 v = vertices[i];
        i++;

        double vertexVal = v.v_[0];
        vOut.v_[0] = vertexVal * m0v0;
        vOut.v_[1] = vertexVal * m0v1;
        vOut.v_[2] = vertexVal * m0v2;
        vOut.v_[3] = vertexVal * m0v3;

        vertexVal = v.v_[1];
        vOut.v_[0] += vertexVal * m1v0;
        vOut.v_[1] += vertexVal * m1v1;
        vOut.v_[2] += vertexVal * m1v2;
        vOut.v_[3] += vertexVal * m1v3;

        vertexVal = v.v_[2];
        vOut.v_[0] += vertexVal * m2v0;
        vOut.v_[1] += vertexVal * m2v1;
        vOut.v_[2] += vertexVal * m2v2;
        vOut.v_[3] += vertexVal * m2v3;

        vertexVal = v.v_[3];
        vOut.v_[0] += vertexVal * m3v0;
        vOut.v_[1] += vertexVal * m3v1;
        vOut.v_[2] += vertexVal * m3v2;
        vOut.v_[3] += vertexVal * m3v3; 

        vertices[i] = vOut;

    } 
}
catch (ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException aioobe) 
{
    // loop is done
}
```